# Same video Stacked horizontaly 5 times

Tags: ffmpeg, stack

I have one video and I would like to stack it horizontally 5 times. 
So output video would be one video file in which i would like to have the same video stacked horizontally for 5 times. 
Any ideas how to do it with ffmpeg script?

thanks.
r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i in -vf "split=5[a][b][c][d][e];[a][b][c][d][e]hstack=5" -c:a copy out
```